# LINQ: Checking if a field (db) contains items in an ILIST?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, extension-methods

I am trying to create an extension method that i can forward a IList of statuses and check weather they exist, I thought the best way to do this was an ILIST - but maybe i wrong? Is this the best way to pass multple items to a method - A List? Its a generic LIST so hence no conversion etc from Object.

Basically I have this as a signature.

```
    public static IQueryable<Building> WithStatus(this IQueryable<Building> qry,
          IList<BuildingStatuses> buildingStatus)
    {

        //PSUEDO CODE 
        //return from v in qry
        //       where v.Status is IN MY LIST called buildingStatus
        //       select v;
    }
```

and to call it i use (example below is in my TDD), it works great the values arrive in my method above.

```
    target.GetBuildings().WithStatus(new List<BuildingFilters.BuildingStatuses>() 
           { BuildingFilters.BuildingStatuses.Available,
             BuildingFilters.BuildingStatuses.Decommissioned });
```

so basically i have my list (IList) it arrives in the extension method with 2 values which is great but need to say in LINQ i need to say

```
        return from v in qry
               where v.Status is IN MY LIST called buildingStatus
               select v;
```

Really appreciate any help,

with regards to my extension method, it works as i have done similar 1 but only passing type BuildingStatus hence only 1...

Comment: Thanks for the two comments, Yes this is great, forgot to mention that i need to call an extension method on each value of List items called GetStringValue, because the list is a collection of Enums named BuildingStatuses, and  GetStringValue is an extension method that returns a string that i added on each Enum via a Attribute. I suppose some kind of lambda could do this?? I am unsure, any ideas?

Comment: If I don't call the extension method (which works) then obviously the enum will return an integer and its a string represenation i need. I hope i am explaining this enough.

Comment: I accepted an answer as my question has wandered a little, and the accepted answer give me the solution i was looking for

Answer (score 5, accepted):

would this work for you:

```
return from v in qry
       where buildingStatus.Contains(v.Status)
       select v;
```

Comment: Does not work with compiled queries although the question is answered.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`IEnumerable<T>.Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb910499.aspx) extension method and allow your method to be more versatile:

```
public static IQueryable<Building> WithStatus(this IQueryable<Building> qry,
          IEnumerable<BuildingStatuses> buildingStatus)
{

    return from v in qry
           where buildingStatus.Contains(v.Status)
           select v;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The suggested approaches I believe are correct... you should also keep in mind the `IEnumerable<T>.Where` method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb910023.aspx